# Unity modify animation at runtime

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

TLDR:
Basically, I use the same animation for all of the soldiers, but I want those animations to behave little different from each other, so all my soldiers won't behave all the same. Would i be able to modify those animation at runtime?

So I'm working on this RTS style game that has a group of soldiers, let's say charging. Since most of them using the same animation. Although I randomize the starting time of each animation, so they won't be played simultaneously. But everybody in the unit is still charging with the same animation. And it looks rather weird.

I wonder if there's a way that I can alter each animation a little bit on runtime, to the degree they swing their arm, for example, one of the soldiers would swing a few degrees more, and other will swing less.

I wonder if it's possible to do in unity at runtime. And if so, how would I do it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, replace your animation with animator controller.

Inside the animator, for example, you can add [animation events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html). You can also define [animation parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html). Based on the parameters you define, your character can switch between different animations. Lets take a look at an example now.

Put a script, SoldierAnimator, on your soldier that has reference to the animator controller.. Now, lets say that your soldier's 'loadGun' animation has 3 variations. You now assign a parameter to each animation. So 'crouchLoad', 'quickLoad' and 'stuckLoad' substates can be assigned parameter 'loadType' with values of 0, 1 and 2.

Assuming that you can go from "Any State" to 'loadGun' state with trigger parameter 'load', and your SoldierAnimator reaches a point where it has to load gun, you can do something like this:

```
public class SoldierAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator _animator;

    void someUserInputEvent()
    {
        //... Some code here...
        loadGun();            
    }

    void loadGun()
    {
        int animType = Random.Range(0, 3);
        _animator.SetInt("loadType", animType);
        _animator.SetTrigger("load"); //Now your animations are randomized



        // You can also experiment with _animator.speed = xx, for 
        // different speeds of loading animation, probably randomized a
        // little, but then add an event to end of the animation and
        // on the event, set speed back to 1.
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest you to do is set up conditions such that when the conditions is met, certain actions would be performed.

Transitions define not only how long the blend between states should take, but also **under what conditions they should activate**.

You can set up a transition to **occur only when certain conditions are true**.

To set up these conditions, specify values of parameters in the **Animator Controller**.

Also you can try : ordered interuptions , transistion offsets or transistion duration to achive your goals.

**Further edits:**

In this case, your higher-level script will need to set the character's animation parameters so that the avatar does what's specified in the text file. It might even be better to use Animator.Play() or .CrossFade() to directly change the animation state rather than setting an animation parameter.

For example, lets say your character 3 twitches at time 02:49. Then at 02:49 the script on character 3 (but only on character 3) should either set a trigger parameter such as "twitch" to true, or play an animation state directly such as Animator.Play("twitch").

So in effect all your soldiers would have different scripts each assigned to them.

Scripts have public properties that you set in the inspector. You can define a property for the character's number. This value would be unique for each character.

does this answer your question? sorry if i still didnt get your question

Comment: How would it be useful in my case? It only transit between different animation in my understanding.

Comment: My bad, Basically, i use the same animation for all of soldiers, but i want those animation to behave little different from each other, so all my soldiers won't behave all the same

Comment: Hi sir. did my answer help you?